# Swift add viewController as a subview to other views

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, subview

I have multiple view controllers which should load a specific view like in this drawing. I defined that view in the storyboard as a separate view controller. The `reusable view controller` has some methods which make the view work.  What's the best way to do this?

I tried using addSubview method but the IBOutlets won't initialize. Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use a [container view](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html).

With a container view, you can embed different view controllers in the same view. Hooking them up is really easy, and can be done within the storyboard.

Comment: Great! Thanks! I'll take a look. How heavy is on the general app?

Comment: @DănuțMihaiFlorian Not heavy at all.

Comment: Weren't you talking about the `container view`? Couldn't find content view anywhere in Object Library...

Comment: Something's not right. I added a container view in a view collection cell and i get an error saying it can't be done.